# Creating a new keyStore file with Webspere wsadmin

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

How do I create a new keystore file with wsadmin tool in websphere.

I tried this command

```
AdminTask.createKeyStore('-keyStoreName <someName> 
                        -keyStoreType PKCS12 
                        -keyStoreLocation <some file location.p12> 
                        -keyStorePassword <pwd> 
                        -keyStorePasswordVerify <pwd>'
                         )
```

but looks like it just loads the keystore in the given location. but i want to create a new keystore and store it in the given location.

What command should I use for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it 'loads keystore'?

I've used the following command:

```
AdminTask.createKeyStore('[-keyStoreName testKS -keyStoreType PKCS12
   -keyStoreLocation c:/testKeyFile.p12 -keyStorePassword testpwd 
   -keyStorePasswordVerify testpwd -keyStoreIsFileBased true
   -keyStoreInitAtStartup true -keyStoreReadOnly false]')
```

and I see keystore correctly created in the file system, and also visible via admin console.

Remember to call `AdminConfig.save()` afterwards to save changes.

See details here [KeyStoreCommands command group for the AdminTask object](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_atkeystore.html?locale=en&ro=kcUI#rxml_atkeystore__cmd3)